# $||Ax||\le\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}||x||$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, summation

> if $x\in\Bbb R^n$, $A\in M_{m\times n}$ with $A_{ij}=a_{ij}$. Then $||Ax||\le\sqrt{\sum_{i,j}a_{ij}^2}||x||$

I am trying to prove this inequality but got stuck. This is needed for an application of perturbation of identity.

**My attempt:**

let $x=(x_1,...,x_n).$ Then $(Ax)_i=\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j$. Now we have $||Ax||=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j)^2}$. But I got stuck here.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you mean $x = (b_{1}, b_{2},.....,b_{n})$ ?

Comment: Which $|.|$ are you considering on $\mathbb{R}^n$ ?

Comment: @P-addict yes, edited. Thank you.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe 2-norm. $||x||:=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2}$

Comment: Apply Cauchy-Schwarz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$||AX||^2 = \sum_{i=1}^n(\sum_{j=1}^na_{ij}x_j)^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \sum_{k=1}^n x_j^2  = \left(\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}^2 \right)||X||^2$$

Answer (score 0):

$\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |a_{ij}|^2}$ is the [Frobenius norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) $\|A\|_F$ of $A$.
You want to prove $\|A\|_2 \le \|A\|_F$, where $\|A\|_2$ is the matrix norm induced by the Euclidean norm on vectors.  This is true because
$\|A\|_2$ is the square root of the maximum eigenvalue of $A^* A$, while $\|A\|_F$ is the square root of $\text{trace}(A^* A)$.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.